# extSDCard as internal Storage - how does Androied manage app & data location

Tags: internal-storage, external-sd

Since Android 6.0 is it possible to use the external SD card as internal storage. If you do so all data on it will be erased and the card will be repartitioned.
I'm quite new to Android > 5.0 but I installed Resurrection Remix OS 3 weeks ago but running again into the storage limitation of my SII (I9100), I used the 1GB/2GB PIT (see *Increase system partition size* or *Lanchon REPIT* on xda).

Anyway as far as I understand, depending on your Android version, you can either use any of the apps such as AppMgr Pro III, Link2SD or App2SD what are able to partition and mount your extSD as internal storage, there is a tutorial on classroom.synonym.com (How to Partition Your SD Card in a Droid for APP2SD). I read all in forums.androidcentral.com ([TUTORIAL] Everything you wanted to know about app2sd, ext3, ext4 partitions!!) but they didn't answer all questions.
Besides, the >Android 6.0 in-build feature is a IMHO more handy.

Anyway, can someone answer the question how Android manage the internal */Data* and */media_rw* partition combined with the external partition before running again in any limitation.
Will I be able to utilise almost all 32 GB or 64 GB of the extSD for apps and their data. I don't take that many pictures with my I9100 due to the poor cam.  I found 2 well explained tutorials (#1 & #2) but both missing this detail.

Answer (score 0):

The adopted SD card is actually mounted at /mnt/expand/$UUID

Instead of forcing the user to pick for EVERY file whether they want it stored in the device's internal storage or the adopted storage, they simply made the internal memory unavailable for storage. That is, /storage/emulated is mounted to point to your adopted SD card and your previous internal storage data that actually lived in /data/media is moved over to its new home on the SD card. This gives the added benefit that there is NO ambiguity where apps are storing user data. It always goes to the adopted SD card.

Go here for more info
[reddit: Let's clear up the confusion regarding storage in Android once and for all, including adoptable storage in Marshmallow.](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/496sn3/lets_clear_up_the_confusion_regarding_storage_in/)

Comment: I finally read the entire post. The sticking point is still _that developers still control whether their app is movable to SD_, in this case the extended internal storage. So you can still run into the limitation of the phones build.in storage.
At at least I can allocate all free space to the _/data_ partition, since I won't need any _/media_ partition since as far as I understand, Android will move all user data, pictures, offline files of streaming services etc to the integrated SD card; please confirm or correct.